# SSRS : Display a text instead of a number

Tags: reporting-services

I have a problem at the moment. I can't do what I want in my Reporting Service.

In my reporting Service I get 3 states for a product :

- State 1 : Product is ordered
- State 2 : Product is customized
- State 3 : Product is finished

So, actually, my column is displaying information like this :

```
1
2
1
1
3
2
1
```

I would like to change the number, by a text. So, I this case, I want to have this result :

```
ORDERED
CUSTOMIZED
ORDERED
ORDERED
FINISHED
CUSTOMIZED
ORDERED
```

Can you help me please ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of different ways. One is using an expression in your data field with an if Condition in the report as follows

```
IIF(Fields!State.Value=1, "ORDERED", IIF(Fields!State.Value=2, "CUSTOMIZED", "FINISHED"))
```

The other way is to do it in query you are calling via your data source using a SQL case statement.

```
SELECT
     CASE
          WHEN StateId = 1 THen 'ORDERED'
          WHEN StateId = 2 Then 'CUSTOMIZED'
          ELSE 'FINISHED'
     END AS State
FROM SomeTable
```